# merge dataset in sas when defining variables aren't perfectly matched

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to merge two datasets so I can get a list of tickers from one set to another. To link the two sets I have a list of company names but there are slightly different spellings throughout.

Here is the code I've used so far which should score the names based on common letters:

```
proc sql;
create table names as 
select *, pcl(tbl1.co_conm,tbl2.company_name) as pcl,
from tbl1, tbl2
having max(pcl)=pcl;
quit;
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You could join them on name using a LIKE statement as an example: proc sql;
SELECT X.* 
  FORM tbl1 X INNER JOIN tbl2 I 
    ON X.co_conm LIKE I.company_name
;
quit;

Comment: Haven't tried the like statement. I'll have to give it a shot in the morning.

Comment: The option is to also use soundex